Laravel Eloquent Query Builder on Pivot
I have a three tables post(Model: Post), user(Model: User) and post_user_pivot for votes.
The Schema of my pivot table
Schema::create('post_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->enum('type', ['up', 'down'])->default('up');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Storing the votes using attach along with the type, up or down.
Fetching the voters like following ways
$post->voters as $voter using foreach()

Each $voter consist of $user as usual.
But what I want to see the current authenticated user is voted or not, and if voted the type of it(up or down) from voters as mentioned above. No iteration just query for that?
Thanks!
I have tried this
$post->voters->find(auth()->user()->id)->wherePivot('type', '=', 'down');


in order to check if a user has voted for a post or not you need to define the reverse relation on the user model:
public function votedPosts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'votes')
                ->withPivot('vote')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

than in your controller you can do something like this:
class PostController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    /** @var User $auth */
    $auth = $request->user();

    $posts = Post::query()->paginate();

    // load user votes for current posts
    $currentVotes = $auth->votedPosts()
      ->whereIn('posts.id', $posts->pluck('id'))
      ->pluck('vote', 'post_id']);
    // resulting array of post_id => vote_type ('up' or 'down')

and in view:
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <div class="card">
    <div class="votes">
      <button class="@if(isset($currentVotes[$post->id]) && $currentVotes[$post->id] == 'up') active @endif" data-post="{{ $post->id }}" data-type="up">
      <button class="@if(isset($currentVotes[$post->id]) && $currentVotes[$post->id] == 'down') active @endif" data-post="{{ $post->id }}" data-type="down">
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach


If you want to see whether the current user has voted or not then you can do something as follows:
$post->voters()
    ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->where('type', 'down')
    ->exists();


First you can improve your migration by replacing unsignedBigInteger with foreignId like so:
Schema::create('post_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->enum('vote', ['up', 'down'])->default('up');
    $table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete(); // or onDelete('set null')
    $table->foreignId('user_id')constrained()->cascadeOnDelete(); // or onDelete('set null')
    $table->timestamps();

    // make sure a user can only vote once for each post
    $table->unique(['user_id', 'post_id']);
});

If you need to access the count of up and down votes frequently, it may help to add another index for post_id and vote.
$table->index(['post_id', 'vote']);

in User model:
public function votedPosts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'votes')
                ->withPivot('vote')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

in Post model:
public function voters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'votes')
                ->withPivot('vote')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

Create a fluent model for updating user's vote on a post (add to Post model):
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Post extends Model
{
    // Define voters relationship as above...

    public function vote(User $user)
    {
        return new class($this, $user) {
            private $post;
            private $user;

            public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
            {
                $this->post = $post;
                $this->user = $user;
            }

            public function up()
            {
                $this->post->voters()->syncWithoutDetaching([
                    $this->user->id => ['vote' => 'up']
                ]);
            }

            public function down()
            {
                $this->post->voters()->syncWithoutDetaching([
                    $this->user->id => ['vote' => 'down']
                ]);
            }
        };
    }
}

I used syncWithoutDetaching to prevent deleting any existing vote, we just want to update the vote.
then update user's vote in a single line like so:
// User casts an "up" vote
$post->vote(Auth::user())->up();

// User changes the vote to "down"
$post->vote(Auth::user())->down();


all of this and you still did not answer the simple question of the post, how to check if the authenticated user has voted a specific post or not

I have got this, to check, if you have voted or not
$post->voters->find(auth()->id())->exists(); //will return true or false

Now, if you are more willingly looking for is it up or down vote
$post->voters()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('type', 'up')->exists();

$post->voters()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('type', 'down')->exists();

Or
Model::where(['column_1' => 'value_1',
              'column_2' => 'value_2'])->get();

